# jQuery- Creating an offset from the top of page for internal anchor tags

Tags: jquery

I have an absolute positioned menu at the top of the page, let's say 50px in height. So, when someone visits a URL on my site like:

```
http://www.example.com/page.html#anchor
```

The page is scrolled 50px too high (covered by the menu).

I am trying to make it so that any time a link is visited with an internal anchor, the page will be offset by 50px, but this is not working:

```
if (document.location.href.indexOf('#') > -1) {

  var leavespace = 50;
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:leavespace}, 'slow');

}
```

I get the slow animated scrolling, but it is still 50px too high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, make sure you have it in a ready function

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  if (document.location.href.indexOf('#') > -1) {

  var leavespace = 50;
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:leavespace}, 'slow');
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hashchange` event for this purpose:

```
$(window).on("hashchange", function () {
    var leavespace = 50
    window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY + leavespace);
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/darevskaya/x2yuF/)

Answer (score 0):

To make it without jquery, I implemented it like (based on Elena's response):

```
window.onhashchange = function (){
        var leavespace = 50
        window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY - leavespace);
    };
```